# How do I average the last 5 minutes of entries from a SQL database?

Tags: sql, average

I have a table that stores time, heart_rate, and player_id. I need to somehow take an average of the heart rate data over the last five minutes and group each average by the player ID.

Comment: What part are you stuck on?  The filter?  The average?  The group by?

Comment: I know how to group it by the player id. The part that is giving me the most trouble is the filter and how to integrate the average into it.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use `DATEDIFF`

```
SELECT  AVG(heart_rate) AS heart_rate,
        player_id
FROM    tablename
WHERE   DATEDIFF(MINUTE, time, GETDATE()) < 5
GROUP BY player_id
```

Comment: Don't use `datediff()`.  It counts the number of minute *boundaries* between the two times.  It doesn't measure the number minutes between two times.

Comment: I like your answer using DateAdd and probably use that method 99% of the time. But can you show me where DateDiff would fail?  Is it a performance issue or just a precision issue?

Comment: It is both a performance and a precision issue.  Performance between the query cannot take advantage of an index for the `where` clause.  Precision, because there is 1 year between 2014-12-31 and 2015-01-01 (1 day, could be 1 second), but 0 years between 2012-01-01 and 2012-12-31 (365 days).  The same thing happens with minutes.

Comment: Is there any way to select the nth entry in the database in the DATEDIFF function? I am not working with recent data, so I need to realistically get the last 300 time entries from the table.

Comment: I actually just answered my own question. I put (SELECT TOP 1 time) in place of GETDATE() and I got what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is partly a response to Donal's answer (and too long for a comment).

You do *not* want to use the following:

```
WHERE datepart(minute, (time - GETDATE())) < 5
```

There are two reasons.  First, this cannot make use of an index on `time`.  That is, the calculation is not sargable.  Second, the subtraction is backwards, unless `time` values are in the future.

A better way to write this is:

```
select player_id, avg(heart_rate)
from table t
where time >= dateadd(minute, -5, getdate())
group by player_id;
```